# How to add data to HTTPBody with put method in android

Tags: android, json, web-services, httprequest, http-put

I am building an android app that uses the Uber API ride request endpoint.I am having trouble regarding appending data in HTTPBody and it is showing error like endpoints are not supported.

These are curl command:

```
curl -X PUT 'https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/requests/{REQUEST_ID}' 
\ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
\ -H 'Authorization: Bearer ' 
\ -d '{"status":"accepted"}'
```

Code:

```
public JSONObject getStatus(String address, String requestId, String product_id, float start_latitude, float start_longitude, float end_latitude, float end_longitude, String token) {
        try {

            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpput = new HttpPut("https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/"+requestId);
            **params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", "accepted"));**

            httpput.setHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+token);
            httpput.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpput.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpput);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();

            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSONStr", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jObj;
    }
```

Comment: how is the server expecting the PUT body? json? xml? url-encoded?

Comment: it requires json format

Comment: actually I am not getting how to append status in HTTPbody

Comment: which http library are you using?

Comment: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 these dependencies I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to the PUT body to be of type `application/json` but you are setting the `httpPut` object's entity to `UrlEncodedFormEntity`
So you need to first fix this. 
First you need to create `StringEntity` object, and set its `contentType` property to `application/json`

In your case since your json string is going to be  `{"status":"accepted"}` you need to instantiate the `StringEntity` class like so

```
StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"status\":\"accepted\"}");
```

And then set the content type like so

```
input.setContentType("application/json");
```

Then set the `httpput` entity property to the input enity we just created like so:

```
httpput.setEntity(input);
```

That's it just replace

```
httpput.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
```

with the first 2 lines

So your code will look like this

**Code:**

```
public JSONObject getStatus(String address, String requestId, String product_id, float start_latitude, float start_longitude, float end_latitude, float end_longitude, String token) {
    try {

        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpput = new HttpPut("https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/"+requestId);
        httpput.setHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+token);
        httpput.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        // Create the string entity
        StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"status\":\"accepted\"}");
        // set the content type to json
        input.setContentType("application/json");
        // set the entity property of the httpput 
        // request to the created input.
        httpput.setEntity(input);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpput);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();

        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSONStr", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;
}
```

if you want to take this to the next step, then you need to ramp up on Json serialization and deserialization in java concepts and learn how to generate json strings from Java objects, then you can serialize Java objects to json strings and instantiate the `StringEntity` with the generated json string.

Comment: then also I am getting error like {"message":"Method not supported for this endpoint.","code":"method_not_allowed"} and I have made changes in above code as per u suggested,
         
            StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"status\":\"accepted\"}");
            input.setContentType("application/json");
            httpput.setEntity(input);

Comment: @RohanChavan Well then that means HttpPut is not allowed try HttpPost instead